# ES6 import statements that assume .jsx ending in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm porting an existing project that was using browserfiy to webpack.  Previously import statements like:

```
import MyClass from './MyClass'
```

...would work.  Now I have to add the .jsx extension

```
import MyClass from './MyClass.jsx'
```

Here's my loader definition:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 10000 // Defaults to 8080
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/app.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/scripts"),
    publicPath: '/scripts',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style!css"
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: [
            "es2015",
            "stage-0",
            "react"
          ],
          plugins: [
            "transform-flow-strip-types"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Any idea how to convince webpack to load without the extension?

Comment: As far as my understanding of webpack goes, that doesn't only depend on the babel loader. Can you include the whole webpack configuration?

Comment: You can just change it to `test: /\.js$/,` if you want the extension to be different.

Comment: Sure, updated @E_net4

Comment: @ToddMoore I want to keep the files as .jsx.  I want to be able to leave off the extension entirely for includes

Comment: `test: /.jsx?$/` should be  `test: /\.jsx?$/,`

Comment: Thanks @QoP.  Didnt seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack relies on the [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) configuration to know which extensions to consider when making module resolution. As of Webpack 4.0.0, the default is `['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json']`, so the `.jsx` extension needs to be added manually. Include this at the root of your webpack configuration object:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.jsx']
},
```